# Returning a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm working in python, trying to write a code that makes the Fibonacci sequence and return the results as a list. How would I go about doing so? I was able to write a code to return the set of values not as a list, but I'm unsure how I would go about writing a code to return a list.

(Here's the code I have to return just the values, just not as a list)

```
def fibo1(par):
var1 = 0
var2 = 1
while var2 < par:
    print var2
    var3 = var1 + var2
    var1 = var2
    var2 = var3   

def main():
    number = int(raw_input("What is the number? "))
    return (fibo1(number))

main()
```

Comment: Aren't youlate for the assignment?  Your classmates were asking this last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Instead of printing `var2`, just add it to a list and return the list once you are done. Here is the working code:

```
def fibo1(par):
    var1 = 0
    var2 = 1
    list = []
    while var2 < par:
        list.append(var2)
        var3 = var1 + var2
        var1 = var2
        var2 = var3   
    return list

def main():
    number = int(raw_input("What is the number? "))
    print fibo1(number)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your fibo1 function to a generator using yield when you want to return values, so you just have to use it as parameter on list function:

```
def fibo1(par):
    var1 = 0
    var2 = 1
    while var2 < par:
        yield var2
        var3 = var1 + var2
        var1 = var2
        var2 = var3   

def main():
    number = int(raw_input("What is the number? "))
    return list(fibo1(number))

print repr(main())
```